# Insert and select the row autoincremented id

Tags: mysql, innodb

What I want to do is insert a row and than select its auto incremented id number, In a multhi-threaded enviroment.

I know how to do it with a `Stored Procedure`.

Will this line of code work:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO table (r1) VALUES (...);
SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
COMMIT;
```

And are there any other options?

Comment: No, this is not the right way. Use [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

Comment: @ypercube , LAST_INSERT_ID() within the same transaction you mean?

Comment: Yes, you can use it at the next statement, just after the insert. Which can be a simple `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();`.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Instead:

```
INSERT ...
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

`LAST_INSERT_ID()` is session-specific, so there is never any confusion with other threads also inserting into the same table.

Also, there is no need for `BEGIN` ... `COMMIT` for this pair of statements.  (You may need it if there are other statements.)

Answer (score -2):

I have practiced that as follows:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO table (r1) VALUES (...);
SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
COMMIT;
```

It gives the following result:

```
BEGIN
INSERT 0 1
id
----
  4
(1 row)

COMMIT
```